# facebook login failed using javascript sdk

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using Facebook login .. but recently i got an error while fetching data for signin / signUp

this's my code

```
  <script>
    // This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
    function statusChangeCallback(response) {
        console.log('statusChangeCallback');
        console.log(response);
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            // Logged into your app and Facebook.
            testAPI();
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            fbLogin();
            // The person is not logged into your app or we are unable to tell.
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +'into this app.';
        }
        else {
            // The person is not logged into your app or we are unable to tell.
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +'into this app.';
        }
    }
    function checkLoginState() {
        FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            statusChangeCallback(response);
        });
    }
    function fbLogin() {
        debugger;
        FB.login(function (response) {
            //if (response.authResponse) {
                console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
                FB.api('/me/?fields=picture,name,email', function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
                    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
                      'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
                });
            //} else {
            //    console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
            //}
        }, { auth_type: 'reauthenticate', auth_nonce: '{random-nonce}' });
    }
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: '393788184007786',
            cookie: true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
            // the session
            xfbml: true,  // parse social plugins on this page
            version: 'v3.2' // The Graph API version to use for the call
        });
    };
    // Load the SDK asynchronously
    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
    // successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
    function testAPI() {
        console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
        FB.api('/me', { fields: 'name,email' }, function (response) {
            var info = response.id + '#' + response.name + '#' + response.email;
            console.log('Successful login for: ' + info);         
        });
    }
</script>
```

and this is button included in html for signin

```
 <fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
                                </fb:login-button>
```

and response from getLoginState() is:

`{ authResponse: undefined, status: "not_authorized" }`

and this's error shown [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HMzY.png)

i'm getting an message in facebook app said " We've restricted this app for violating the Facebook Platform Policies"

any suggestions for solving this issue?!!

Comment: are you using a correct app id? you can share the original code here, no need to hide the app id in "{MYAPPID}". it will be in the client code anyway. only app secret and access tokens should be kept secret.

Comment: Yes , it's correct . i have edited it with the orginal one.

Comment: see my answer. if that does not solve it, please include the login code in your question. i could not find it.

Answer (score 0):

The brackets are just placeholders, you have to remove them:

```
FB.init({
    appId: '393788184007786',
    cookie: true, 
    xfbml: true,  
    version: 'v3.2' 
});
```

Comment: it didn't solve it.. i have included my login button and all js code in the question .. 
but i'm getting an message in facebook app said"We've restricted this app for violating the Facebook Platform Policies" does this restriction prevents me from using app for fetching data of new users in my website ??

Comment: actually i made an  appeal to Facebook 6 days ago about this restriction but they didn't reply till now ... i was trying many solution by using login button or fb.login .. to see if it may help solving issue

Comment: but it works fine with registered users with facebook in my website .. this problem happens with new user when he tries to sign up with his facebook account , i can't fetch data

Comment: existing users don´t need to open the login popup, i guess that´s why it still works for them. you should also add your app settings as a screenshot in your question....but if it´s restricted, i guess all you can do is wait until facebook replies.

Comment: i will wait and see after facebook replies ,if it's solved i will post app settings to check again .. thanks in advance